# Gradle: Make a project depend on the output of another project in a multi project build

Tags: gradle

I have two projects in a multi project build. One looks like this:

```
// project-a build.gradle

task generateJar(type: Exec) {
   commandLine "command", "to", "generate", "jar"
}

task generateArtifact(type: Zip, dependsOn: generateJar) {
    outputs.file("/path/to/generated/jar")
}

artifacts { archives generateArtifact }
```

And the other simply depends on it like so:

```
// project-b build.gradle

dependencies {
    implementation project(':project-a')
}
```

My expectation is that when I run a build on project b, it will first try to run generateArtifact + generateJar from project a, then get the outputted jar for use in project b, however I just get a "package does not exist" error in :project-b:compileJava. Based on the output, it looks like it is not trying to run any tasks in project-a, almost like it doesn't recognize the dependency exists

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing up project and task dependencies. While you correctly made `project-b` depend on `project-a`, that does not automatically mean your custom `generateJar` and `generateArtifact` tasks get executed. You still need to mark your JAR in `project-a` [as an "outgoing" artifact or add it to the output of the main source set which you can depend on in the consuming project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:depending_on_output_of_another_project) like so:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        output.file(generateArtifact.outputFile, builtBy: generateArtifact)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With 'compile' split into 'implementation' and 'api' configuration the behaviour might have changed. Can you just try with 'compile'(its deprecated though) once, to validate this.  If it works then it means as suggsted by @sschuberth you may have to handle to explicitly call the generateArtifact of :projecta when you build  :projectb.